# JS group by month of date values (objects) in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping

My array is like this:

```
myArray = [
  {date: "2017-01-01", num: "2"}
  {date: "2017-01-02", num: "3"}
  {date: "2017-02-04", num: "6"}
  {date: "2017-02-05", num: "15"}
]
```

I want to convert this into:

```
myArray = [
   {group: "0", data: [
      {date: "2017-01-01", num: "2"}
      {date: "2017-01-02", num: "3"}]
   },
   {group: "1", data: [  
      {date: "2017-02-04", num: "6"}
      {date: "2017-02-05", num: "15"}]
   },
]
```

Basically, group by month of date key.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 10):

The solution using `Array.prototype.reduce`, `String.prototype.split` and `Array.prototype.map` functions:

```js
var myArray = [
    {date: "2017-01-01", num: "2"},
    {date: "2017-01-02", num: "3"},
    {date: "2017-02-04", num: "6"},
    {date: "2017-02-05", num: "15"}
],
    groupKey = 0;
    groups = myArray.reduce(function (r, o) {
        var m = o.date.split(('-'))[1];
        (r[m])? r[m].data.push(o) : r[m] = {group: String(groupKey++), data: [o]};
        return r;
    }, {});

var result = Object.keys(groups).map(function(k){ return groups[k]; });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: How to do exact same thing but sum all values (nums) by group without putting them to data array? Just wanna group and sum value.

Answer (score 7):

## Pro Solution (One Liner):

If you don't already have [Lodash](https://lodash.com) (same as [Underscore JS](https://underscorejs.org)), add it to your JS, like this:

Install with NPM: `npm i --save lodash`

## The Solution Code:

I will show you a beautiful one liner in Lodash (or Underscore.js)

```
const _ = require('lodash');
let myArray = [
  {date: "2017-01-01", num: "2"},
  {date: "2017-01-02", num: "3"},
  {date: "2017-02-04", num: "6"},
  {date: "2017-02-05", num: "15"}
]

// The one liner
_.groupBy(myArray, ({date})=> new Date(date).getMonth());
```

This is the response:

```
{
    "0": [
           {
            "date": "2017-01-01",
            "num": "2"
           },
           {
            "date": "2017-01-02",
            "num": "3"
           }
    ],
    "1": [
           {
            "date": "2017-02-04",
            "num": "6"
           },
           {
            "date": "2017-02-05",
            "num": "15"
           }
    ]
}
```

[Group By Reference](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy)